# In Laravel, passing a file in a custom http request

Tags: php, symfony, laravel

I'm trying to test a controller method that accepts a file in its request.

In my test I have the following line:

```
$this->call('POST', 'image/upload', ['image' => $image]);
```

Where `$image` is a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile` instance.

In the controller method I'm testing it accepts the request object and retrieves the uploaded file via:

```
$image = $request->file('image');
```

However the file is only available via `$request->get('image');` when the action is called via my custom http request above. (An ordinary request from the browser produces the expected behaviour).

How can I pass the file into the `file` part of the request object?

Comment: most likely it sending the file  with  `GET` instead of  `POST`. Where is your html form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the file in as part of the `$_POST` global where you should be setting it in the `$_FILE` global.

To do that, I believe you pass the file in as the 5th parameter.

```
$this->call('POST', 'image/upload', [], [], ['image' => $image]);
```

Then you should be able to grab it using `$request->file('image')`

Comment: It's actually the fifth parameter. [Method signature](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/CrawlerTrait.php#L908)